# Windows Network Drive Map for AS400 IFS (IBM iSeries)

Tags: ibm-midrange

How do I map a windows network drive to an AS400 (IBM iSeries) IFS folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To map to an IFS folder from a Windows machine on the network, you must first share it using iSeries Navigator.  Ask your AS/400 server admin, or someone with enough authority to create the share.  Here are instructions for creating a share:

1. Open iSeries Navigator
2. Connect to your AS/400 system.
3. Expand Network->Servers
4. Click TCP/IP to see a list of servers.
5. Right-click on iSeries NetServer and click Open
6. Right-click on shared objects and then click New and then File.

You also need to have the netserver job running on the AS/400.  You can start it from iSeries Navigator or using the following AS/400 command if it isn't running:

```
STRTCPSVR SERVER(*NETSVR)
```

After that, you map just like any Windows server.  You can use the NET USE command, right-click on my computer and map a drive, or type the address in your explorer window like \\NetServerName\

A big issue to consider is the name of your net server does not have to be the same as the name of your AS/400.  Many systems like to put a Q in front of the name as the netserver name.  You'll find this in the NetServer properties screen in iSeries Navigator.  You **may** have to add this system name to your local hosts file or your DNS server, if you have access to that.

Answer (score 5):

A Customer of mine has an AS/400 and after an OS upgrade last week on the '400 they wondered about getting a copy of "Client Access" off of the system using the Windows File and Print Sharing protocol.

I found that I could get a "drive mapping" to the AS/400 by executing the following from a command-prompt:

```
NET USE * \\as-400-name-or-ip\QIBM /USER:as-400-username as-400-password
```

Put quotes around the AS/400 password if it has spaces in it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have NetServer running on the AS/400 and then you can map to the IFS.